# Java Game : How to place one tile over another tile

Tags: java

Hi I am making a java game in were you can build land. at the moment when you place tile A on top of TileB it renders over it but when you place TileB on top of TileA it doesn't render it stays as tileA. so how  could I have it so that it either one renders on top of each other.
I think I might need to remove a tile from the array and then that space is free. But I don't know how to remove the tile that the mouse is hovering over from the array maybe that would help.
my code.

```
public static ArrayList<hellstone> hpf = new ArrayList<hellstone>();
public static ArrayList<lava> lava = new ArrayList<lava>();

public void render() {
    Graphics g = screen.getGraphics();

    // drawing things.

    if (time < timer / 2) {
        ImageIcon i2 = new ImageIcon("res/lava.png");
        img = i2.getImage();
        g.drawImage(img, 0, 0, null);

    }
    if (time > timer / 2) {
        ImageIcon i2 = new ImageIcon("res/lava1.png");
        img = i2.getImage();
        g.drawImage(img, 0, 0, null);

    }
    for (int i = 0; i < castles.toArray().length; i++) {
        castles.get(i).render(g);
    }
    /*
     * g.setColor(Color.blue); g.fillRect(10,10,40,20);
     * g.setColor(Color.black); g.drawString("ADD", 16, 24);
     * g.setColor(Color.black); g.drawRect(9, 9, 41, 21);
     */

    if (play) {
        // bg----------

        ImageIcon i3 = new ImageIcon("res/hellbackgorund.png");
        img = i3.getImage();
        g.drawImage(img, 0, 0, null);

        // ImageIcon i2 = new ImageIcon("res/hellsun.png");
        // img = i2.getImage();
        // g.drawImage(img, 120, 80, null);
        for (int i = 0; i < lava.toArray().length; i++) {
            lava.get(i).render(g);
        }

        for (int i = 0; i < hous.toArray().length; i++) {
            hous.get(i).render(g);
        }

        for (int i = 0; i < hpf.toArray().length; i++) {
            hpf.get(i).render(g);
        }
        for (int i = 0; i < b.toArray().length; i++) {
            b.get(i).render(g);
        }

        for (int i = 0; i < orc.toArray().length; i++) {
            orc.get(i).render(g);
        }
        g.setColor(Color.YELLOW);
        g.drawString("" + money, 20, 10);
        ImageIcon i5 = new ImageIcon("res/coin.png");
        img = i5.getImage();
        g.drawImage(img, 2, 2, null);




        g.setColor(new Color(0,255,0,70));
        g.fillRect(((Comp.mx/2) /20) * 20 ,((Comp.my/2) / 20) * 20 , 20, 20);

        inventory.render(g);

    }
    for (int i = 0; i < gamemenu.toArray().length; i++) {
        gamemenu.get(i).render(g);
    }
    level.render(g);

    g = getGraphics();

    g.drawImage(screen, 0, 0, size.width, size.height, 0, 0, pixel.width,
            pixel.height, null);
    g.dispose();
}
```

*****the mosue listenr***************

```
public void mouseReleased(MouseEvent e) {
    if (e.getButton() == MouseEvent.BUTTON1) {
        Comp.ml = false;
        if (Comp.play && Comp.money >= 100) {

            if(inventory.sel == 0){
                //(mouse.x / gridCellWidh)*gridCellWidth
            Comp.hpf.add(new hellstone(((Comp.mx/2) /20) * 20 ,((Comp.my/2) / 20) * 20 ));
            Comp.money -= 100;
            }else if(inventory.sel == 1){
                Comp.b.add(new board(((Comp.mx/2) /20) * 20 ,((Comp.my/2) / 20) * 20 ));
                Comp.money -= 100;
            }else if(inventory.sel == 2){
                Comp.hous.add(new house(((Comp.mx/2) /20) * 20 ,((Comp.my/2) / 20) * 20 ));
                Comp.money -= 400;
            }

        }
    } else if (e.getButton() == MouseEvent.BUTTON3) {
        Comp.mr = false;
        if (Comp.play && Comp.Orcs < 99) {

            Comp.orc.add(new orc(new Random().nextInt(100),new Random().nextInt(100),Color.green));
        }

    }

}
```

---

please help me figure this out.

Comment: You need to change the order in which you draw the tiles. Always draw the tiles you want on the bottom first.

Comment: I know that so if I draw tile A fist and then tile B I can place tile B on top of tile A but I cant place tile a on top of tile B

Answer (score 2):

The problem here is your drawing order. No matter what order your tiles are enabled, each one is drawn in a specific order. No matter what order blocks are added, Lava is always drawn first, which means that any other block in the same place will cover it up because it is drawn later in the loop. The way you have your drawing system will not allow lava to cover up anything for example. You need to rethink your approach to drawing the tiles, either add a flag to indicate which was last placed, or use 2D lists/arrays.

Comment: I have absolutely no idea how to do that an u help out maybe a suggestion on what way to approach it  or code if u want but I rather a suggestion on how to do it